# Pandas: Search for dataframe row by string then modify [without header]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A bit of pickle. I am trying to find a single row in a dataframe by searching for a specific string value, then replace the string value with zero. I am using the following code:

```
selectRow = df[df.iloc[:,0].str.match(ID)]

selectRow.replace(ID, 0)
```

where ID is some string. 
This returns one row within the dataframe as expected.
However, I can't seem to modify the values of the *selectRow* in dataframe, as the *selectRow* is a separate dataframe at this point.

I know I am missing something incredibly basic. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

CN

Comment: P.S. dataframe I am working on is without header, and I would prefer to keep it that way - ideally.

Comment: you can just assign it in your first call provided you know which column it is you want to change based on index

Comment: after `replace`, try update `selectRow` back to `df` as:  `df.update(selectRow)`

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on "assigning it to the first call"? I've tried df.update but it didn't make any changes. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in a single line as follows:

### Method-1:

```py
ID = `eee`
df.iloc[:,0].loc[df.iloc[:,0]==ID] = 0
```

**Output**:

```
        C1   C2
0      aaa  bbb
1      ccc  ddd
2        0  fff
3  ggg eee  hhh
```

### Method-2:

Use [`pandas.Dataframe.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method.

```py
df.iloc[:,0].replace(to_replace=ID, value=0, regex=False)
```

**Output**:

```
        C1   C2
0      aaa  bbb
1      ccc  ddd
2        0  fff
3  ggg eee  hhh
```

If you set **`regex=True`**, that could adjust the rows based on other occurrences of the `ID` as well.
**Output**:

```
        C1   C2
0      aaa  bbb
1      ccc  ddd
2        0  fff
3        0  hhh
```

### Dummy Data

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['aaa','bbb'],['ccc','ddd'],['eee','fff'],['ggg eee','hhh']], columns=['C1','C2'])
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
        C1   C2
0      aaa  bbb
1      ccc  ddd
2      eee  fff
3  ggg eee  hhh
```

Answer (score 0):

test data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['aaa','bbb'],['ccc','ddd'],['eee','fff'],['ggg','hhh']])
```

df is:

```
    Out[42]: 
         0    1
    0  aaa  bbb
    1  ccc  ddd
    2  eee   fff
    3  ggg  hhh
```

code:

```
Template = 'eee'
df[0] = [(lambda x: 0 if (x == Template) else x)(x) for x in df[0]]
```

Result is:

```
Out[45]: 
         0    1
    0  aaa  bbb
    1  ccc  ddd
    2    0  fff
    3  ggg  hhh
```

Does it help?